# Execute statement every N iterations in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a very long loop, and I would like to check the status every N iterations, in my specific case I have a loop of 10 million elements and I want to print a short report every millionth iteration.

So, currently I am doing just (n is the iteration counter):

```
if (n % 1000000==0):
    print('Progress report...')
```

but I am worried I am slowing down the process by computing the modulus at each iteration, as one iteration lasts just few milliseconds.

Is there a better way to do this? Or shouldn't I worry at all about the modulus operation?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about keeping a counter and resetting it to zero when you reach the wanted number? Adding and checking equality is faster than modulo.

```
printcounter = 0

# Whatever a while loop is in Python
while (...):   
    ...
    if (printcounter == 1000000):
        print('Progress report...')
        printcounter = 0
    ...
    printcounter += 1
```

Although it's quite possible that the compiler is doing some sort of optimization like this for you already... but this may give you some peace of mind.

Comment: thanks, this looks like the best solution, but I understand I should really profile the code to have a definite answer.

Comment: This is something that is very easy to think, only if you know you can do something like this :-) Great Answer, helped me twice.

Comment: @AndreaZonca On second glance, I tend to agree.  I don't see where this example modulates.  Every iteration, something should happen (and indeed seems to); however, every 5th iteration, something special should happen--I don't recognize that.  I wish I were able to program better so that I could test solutions more carefully.

Answer (score 29):

### 1. Human-language declarations for `x` and `n`:

let x be the number of iterations that have been examined at any given time.
let n be the multiple of iterations upon which your code will executed.

Example 1: "After x iterations, how many times was n done?"

Example 2: "It is the xth iteration and the action has occurred every nth time, so far."

### 2. What we're doing:

**The first code block (Block A)** uses only one variable, x (defined above), and uses 5 (an integer) rather than the variable n (defined above).

**The second code block (Block B)** uses both of the variables (x and n) that are defined above.  The integer, 5, will be replaced by the variable, n.  So, **Block B literally performs an action at each nth iteration**.

Our goal is to do one thing on every iteration and two things on every nth iteration.
We are going through 100 iterations.

### m. Easy-to-understand attempt:

### Block A, minimal variables:

```
for x in 100:
    #what to do every time (100 times in-total): replace this line with your every-iteration functions.
    if x % 5 == 0:
        #what to do every 5th time: replace this line with your nth-iteration functions.
```

### Block B, generalization.

```
n = 5
for x in 100:
    #what to do every time (100 times in-total): replace this line with your every-iteration functions.
    if x % n == 0:
        #what to do every 5th time: replace this line with your nth-iteration functions.
```

Please, let me know if you have any issues because I haven't had time to test it after writing it here.

### 3. Exercises

1. If you've done this properly, see if you can use it with the turtle.Pen() and turtle.forward() function.  For example, move the turtle forward 4 times and then right and forward once?
2. See if you can use this program with the turtle.circle() function.  For example, draw a circle with radius+1 4 times and a circle of a new color with radiut+1 once?
3. Check out the reading (seen below) to attempt to improve the programs from exercise 1 and 2.  I can't think of a good reason to be doing this: I just feel like it might be useful!

About modulo and other basic operators:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

About turtle:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html
https://michael0x2a.com/blog/turtle-examples

Answer (score 13):

Is it really slowing down? You have to try and see for yourself. It won't be much of a slowdown, but if we're talking about nanoseconds it may be considerable. Alternatively you can convert one 10 million loop to two smaller loops:

```
m = 1000000
for i in range(10):
    for i in range(m):
        // do sth
    print("Progress report")
```

Comment: thanks, good solution, this is better if the total length is a multiple of the report length, AndrewKS's answer is more general.

Comment: If I set m to 10, would I get something only every 5th iteration?

Answer (score 9):

It's difficult to know how your system will optimize your code without testing.

You could simplify the relational part by realizing that zero is evaluated as false.

```
if(not N % 10000000)
   do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like that ? :

```
for n in xrange(1000000,11000000,1000000):
    for i in xrange(n-1000000,n):
        x = 10/2
    print 'Progress at '+str(i)
```

result

```
Progress at 999999
Progress at 1999999
Progress at 2999999
Progress at 3999999
Progress at 4999999
Progress at 5999999
Progress at 6999999
Progress at 7999999
Progress at 8999999
Progress at 9999999
```

.

EDIT

Better:

```
for n in xrange(0,10000000,1000000):
    for i in xrange(n,n+1000000):
        x = 10/2
    print 'Progress at '+str(i)
```

And inspired from pajton:

```
m = 1000000
for n in xrange(0,10*m,m):
    for i in xrange(n,n+m):
        x = 10/2
    print 'Progress at '+str(i+1)
```

I prefer this that I find more immediately readable than the pajton's solution.
It keeps the display of a value depending of **i**

Comment: I can't tell, honestly.  I thought something would jump out at me on the 5th iteration.  This seems to be incrementation rather than modulating incrementation.  If I add something between for n and for i, will I also see something at every iteration?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do some testing to see how much time your modulus calls are consuming.  You can use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) for that.  If your results indicate a need for time reduction, another approach which eliminates your modulus calculation:

```
for m in xrange(m_min, m_max):
    for n in xrange(n_min, n_max):
        #do_n_stuff
    print('Progress report...')
```

Comment: This. The answer is "don't ever optimize without first establishing that there's really a need".

Comment: Can I just add #do_x_stuff on line 2 to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: If you literally add "do_n_stuff", nothing will change, as that's a comment! Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean - if you add the code you want execute, it should work. However, note that the above is for Python 2.

Comment: Well, the point is that there are a lot of answers, but the explanations of the answers are explanations I'm not comprehending well.  The goal is, for example, to have operation1 occur every 5th iteration and operation2 occur every 7th iteration.  So, on the 35th iteration, both things would happen; on the 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th, 25th, and 30th, only op1 would happen; on the 7th, 14th, 21st, and 28th iteration, only op2 would happen.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: If you must have things happen in different frequencies, I expect this approach would be difficult to adapt. You probably want to run a single loop with multiple modulus checks. Please give that a try and if you can't get it working, please post a separate question - it's too difficult to explain in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's fast enough that I wouldn't worry about it.

If you really wanted to speed it up, you could do this to avoid the modulus

```
if (n == 1000000):
    n = 0
    print('Progress report...')
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes the inner loop lean, and `m` does not have to be divisible by `interval`.

```
m = 10000000
interval = 1000000
i = 0
while i < m:
    checkpoint = min(m, i+interval)
    for j in xrange(i, checkpoint):
        #do something
    i = checkpoint
    print "progress"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing timing/reports based on count iterations, I just divide my counter by the desired iteration and determine if the result is an integer.  So:

```
    if n/1000000 == int(n/1000000):
        print(report)
```